# how to configure ctrl + shift + O shortcut in monaco editor to show all the files?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor, react-monaco-editor

I am creating an online web ide, that has a file explorer and supports multiple tabs & I am using [Monaco](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) for the same.

Just like in VsCode, we can open the command palette by typing `ctrl + shift + p`. Similarly, in monaco editor, we can open command palette using `ctrl + shift + o`.

But, how can I add these files option in my monaco editor as well.

[image: VScode editor listing all the files]
*VsCode showing the files present*

[image: monco editor not listing any files]
*monaco editor not showing any files, how to configure this?*